# How to fetch HTML raw code in Backtick for string interpolation in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making resume builder, the html template file is saved in firebase storage and using url i fetch the data. Template is already been modified for string interpolation for example `<h1>${name}</h1>`. now when i fetch the data using axio and the name variable is already been defined in component and using dangerouslysetinnerhtml i render the html in react. its shows the html exactly like how it is without interpolation. I know it can be done using backtick but how to work around to make it like the html is surrounded by backtick.
This is what is want:

```js
name = 'react'
const data = axios.get(url)
//data = '<h1>${name}</h1>'

return (
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }} />
)
```

Expected Output: React
Actual output: ${name}

Comment: I don't know how you would get this working, but if you did, it seems exceptionally venerable to script injection. You might not need to worry about that, but if you can share/send the data, this is not the best approach.

Comment: will sanitizing the request data before rendering make it less venerable?

Answer (score 1):

Using a proper template engine is usually the best approach, because it will protect you from XSS.

However, if you don't need to worry about XSS (for example because the HTML files are treated like source files i.e hardcoded and only edited by you), then you can use eval:

```
const name = 'bob';
const data = '<h1>${name}</h1>'
const result = eval('`'+data+'`');
console.log(result) // <h1>bob</h1>
```

Comment: bro, it worked perfect, thanks. One thing i wanna ask if i sanitize the requested data will it still prone to XSS attack if so what would be the best approach to do what i wanted to do as explained above

Comment: It would be difficult to sanitise as is and might not be secure. You could use a template engine like Handlebars which is safe.